# When I feed an image to my trained model, it gives 80%+ accuracy to objects that are not trained in the model

Tags: c#, python, opencv, tensorflow, keras

I'm working on **Unity-Android** application which recognizes hand gestures. The images I used to train the model are **50x50 Black and White Images** with hand segmented through **HSV values**. Now, the same is being done when testing the model but the issue is:
When there is no hand in the camera, it still detects something (anything -through a mobile camera) because HSV is not accurate and when that image with **(no hand) is fed to the model** it still gives **80%+ accuracy on it and determines a random class for it.**

Images and Code through which the model is trained is linked down.

> I am using **TensorflowSharp** to load my model.
>   For openCV I am using **OpenCV for Unity**
>   I have **4 gestures** (4 classes), where each class has 4-4.5k images total of 17k images. Sample images

Class 1

[image: Class 1]

Class 2

[image: Class 2]

Class 3

[image: Class 3]

Class 4

[image: Class 4]

If u need any other information please do tell me, any help will be appreciated.

- I have tried hand detection models so it can detect when there is no hand but they are not accurate.
- I have tried an input from the user to touch where his hand is, it works fine but when the hand is removed it again starts to detect randomly because of the HSV.
- I tried feature matching through SIFT etc. but they are very costly.
- I tried template matching which from my perspective should work but is giving some weird results.

```
using (var graph = new TFGraph())
{
graph.Import(buffer);
using (var session = new TFSession(graph))
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    var runner = session.GetRunner();
    Mat gray = new Mat();
    Mat HSVMat = new Mat();
    Imgproc.resize(touchedRegionRgba, gray, new
    OpenCVForUnity.Size(50, 50));
    Imgproc.cvtColor(gray, HSVMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV_FULL);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(gray, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
    for (int i = 0; i < gray.rows(); i++)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 200; count<gray.cols(); j++)
        {
            double[] Hvalue = HSVMat.get(i, count);
            if (!((detector.mLowerBound.val[0] <= Hvalue[0] && Hvalue[0] <= detector.mUpperBound.val[0]) &&
                (detector.mLowerBound.val[1] <= Hvalue[1] && Hvalue[1] <= detector.mUpperBound.val[1]) &&
                (detector.mLowerBound.val[2] <= Hvalue[2] && Hvalue[2] <= detector.mUpperBound.val[2])))
            {
                gray.put(i, count, new byte[] { 0 });
            }
        }
    }
    var tensor = Util.ImageToTensorGrayScale(gray);
    //runner.AddInput(graph["conv1_input"][0], tensor);
    runner.AddInput(graph["zeropadding1_1_input"][0], tensor);
    //runner.Fetch(graph["outputlayer/Softmax"][0]);
    //runner.Fetch(graph["outputlayer/Sigmoid"][0]);
    runner.Fetch(graph["outputlayer/Softmax"][0]);
    var output = runner.Run();
    var vecResults = output[0].GetValue();
    float[,] results = (float[,])vecResults;
    sw.Stop();
    int result = Util.Quantized(results);
    //numberOfFingersText.text += $"Length={results.Length} Elapsed= {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms, Result={result}, Acc={results[0, result]}";
    }
}
```

```py
# EDITED MODEL, MODEL 1

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.ZeroPadding2D((2, 2), batch_input_shape=(None, 50, 50, 1), name="zeropadding1_1"))   

#54x54 fed in due to zero padding
model.add(layers.Conv2D(8, (5, 5), activation='relu', name='conv1_1'))
model.add(layers.ZeroPadding2D((2, 2), name="zeropadding1_2"))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(8, (5, 5), activation='relu', name='conv1_2'))

model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name="maxpool_1")) #convert 50x50 to 25x25

#25x25 fed in
model.add(layers.ZeroPadding2D((2, 2), name="zeropadding2_1"))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(16, (5, 5), activation='relu', name='conv2_1'))
model.add(layers.ZeroPadding2D((2, 2), name="zeropadding2_2"))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(16, (5, 5), activation='relu', name='conv2_2'))

model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((5, 5), strides=(5, 5), name="maxpool_2")) #convert 25x25 to 5x5

#5x5 fed in
model.add(layers.ZeroPadding2D((2, 2), name="zeropadding3_1"))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(40, (5, 5), activation='relu', name='conv3_1'))
model.add(layers.ZeroPadding2D((2, 2), name="zeropadding3_2"))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='relu', name='conv3_2'))

model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Flatten())

model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.15))
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.1))
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))

model.add(layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax', name="outputlayer"))
```

```py
# MODEL 2, used a few more that I haven't mentioned

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.ZeroPadding2D((2, 2), batch_input_shape=(None, 50, 50, 1), name="zeropadding1_1"))   

#54x54 fed in due to zero padding
model.add(layers.Conv2D(8, (5, 5), activation='relu', name='conv1_1'))
model.add(layers.ZeroPadding2D((2, 2), name="zeropadding1_2"))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(8, (5, 5), activation='relu', name='conv1_2'))

model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name="maxpool_1")) #convert 50x50 to 25x25

#25x25 fed in
model.add(layers.ZeroPadding2D((2, 2), name="zeropadding2_1"))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(16, (5, 5), activation='relu', name='conv2_1'))
model.add(layers.ZeroPadding2D((2, 2), name="zeropadding2_2"))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(16, (5, 5), activation='relu', name='conv2_2'))

model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((5, 5), strides=(5, 5), name="maxpool_2")) #convert 25x25 to 5x5

#5x5 fed in
model.add(layers.ZeroPadding2D((2, 2), name="zeropadding3_1"))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(40, (5, 5), activation='relu', name='conv3_1'))
model.add(layers.ZeroPadding2D((2, 2), name="zeropadding3_2"))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='relu', name='conv3_2'))

model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Flatten())

model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='tanh'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='tanh'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.15))
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='tanh'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.1))
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='tanh'))
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='tanh'))
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='tanh'))
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='tanh'))
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='tanh'))

model.add(layers.Dense(4, activation='sigmoid', name="outputlayer"))
```

Expected results: Higher accuracy on the actual 4 classes of the trained model and lower on the rest.

Actual Results: Higher accuracy on the actual 4 classes as well as the rest of the images fed to it.

Comment: I guess this means "80%+ accuracy on it" something like confidence score? Because 80%+ accuracy does not seem too bad.

Comment: So, you have images where the net should predict 'no gesture' but it predicts some random class. Why don't you add an output for a 'no gesture' class? You can probably used your pre-trained model, too, and just replace the last layer.

Comment: @Eypros: assuming the "80%+" is meant to be as the output of Model 1, the softmax layer can indeed be interpreted as a probability, as it scales the output to sum to 1. For model 2 this is not possible, due to the sigmoid activation.

Comment: @Gregor accuracy usually refers to a metric comparing the predicted values to the ground truth one not to a fancy way to name the predicted values scores.

Comment: probably a bad question, but: did your training data include lots of negative examples, i.e. examples without a hand in them? did it do a good job of classifying them? meaning: can we reasonably *expect* it to classify your negatives?

Comment: With four output classes, how can he have negative examples (the gestures are attached)? That's why I thought the "accuracy" was meant to be the probability of the output layer. With a softmax it will be "quite hard" to give each class an output value close to 0...

Comment: did you try using only the "value" channel of your hsv image?

Comment: @Eypros 80%+ accuracy is on objects that are not within these classes, that can be anything other than these. Which is not good because i cannot threshold it as well

Comment: @Gregor I had that idea in mind but what do u classify as 'no gesture' there can be infinite number of objects which do not relate to these specific classes. Can u please elaborate a little more

Comment: @Gregor yes, but model 2 has other problems like even if it returns the highest value of 0.3-0.4 i.e. 30-40% it does so for anything not just the gestures. What I'm trying to say is that its hard to classify that if it is one of the gesture or something other than the gesture

Comment: @MarcGravell no my training data does not have negative examples, it has exactly these gestures but there is a bit noise in them as well to handle noisy data

Comment: @Micka, what do u think I should do with the value channel? It is basically just the intensity values which vary too much depending on the light

Comment: @MuhammadHumza if you didn't include negative examples in the training data... I would *expect* it to be completely useless (meaning: can give false positives, false negatives, anything) when facing that kind of data... that is *part of the training*, no? If you give it data completely unrelated to the training set: you shouldn't expect good results

Comment: @MarcGravell the model is trained on the above 4 types of images. if you are talking about negative examples than what are negative examples? everything that is not these 4 images and there is no limit to it.

And on the second part, I'm not giving it data unrelated to training data but suppose when there is no hand in front of the camera. Some sort of data is still being fed to the model and the model is giving good accuracy even on that data with random classification.
If my answer is not according to your question can u please elaborate? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me, the basic problem is that you are not able to **detect whether a hand is present in the image**. You need to localise the hand.

1. First, we need to detect whether the hand is present or not. You can try **Siamese networks** for these tasks. I have used them succesfully in detecting skin abnormalities. You can refer this -> 
   **“One Shot Learning with Siamese Networks using Keras” by Harshall Lamba** https://link.medium.com/xrCQOD8ntV and **“Facial Similarity with Siamese Networks in PyTorch” by Harshvardhan Gupta** https://link.medium.com/htBzNmUCyV
2. The network would give a binary output. If the hand is present then values closer to one will be seen. Otherwise, values closer to zero will be seen.

Other, ML models like YOLO are used for object localization, but Siamese networks are simple and sober.

> Siamese networks actually use the same CNN and hence they are siamese or conjoined. They measure the absolute error between the image embeddings and try to approximate a similarity function between the images.

After, proper detection, classification could be done.

Comment: yes you got it right the whole problem is hand detection. If through some algorithm I have a hand detected 'efficiently' this whole problem will be resolved.
Okay let me study this and i'll get back to you.
One more thing is that as I have mentioned I'm using android and of course there are limitations - processing wise, do u think siamese network can efficiently tell if hand is present or not?

Comment: Yes, they are efficient in this task. Also, accept the answer if you think it is useful.

Comment: Yes, thank you Shubham I'll definitely try it, can u please suggest me a way that is better than HSV and detects the region of hand?

Comment: Due to the lack of knowledge, I may not be able to share that information.

Comment: i don't think there's an implementation of siamese network in C#, I have been trying to find it but failed